# What permissions levels allow for approving a calendar and viewing a draft

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, permissions, versioning

I have 4 security groups that have the below permissions:

1. Full Control
2. Edit
3. Contribute
4. Read

For the above permissions who can approve a calendar entry?
For the above permissions who can view a rejected or pending calendar entry ?

Note the calendar Versioning Draft settings are: 
*Require Content Approval
*Only users who can approve items and the author of the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approve permissions require Design or higher permissions. In your scenario only the users with Full control would be able to view and approve drafts. The author can also view their items but no-one else other than approvers (Full Control).

If you wish to give a group Approve but not full control I would either create a specific group for approvers with Design permissions or change the group with Edit permissions to Design permissions, which ever makes more sense for your requirements.